# In LINUX C/C++, which system calls are interruptable (i.e. errno == EINTR)?

Tags: c, linux, signals, system-calls

Does anyone know of a good reference that lists which calls are interruptable?

I was assuming pretty much all system calls were previously, but looking at the man pages for filesystem calls like *open* or *rename*, the list of errors doesn't include *EINTR*.

Comment: [Bottom of page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html), what's important for you is the list of functions that are _never_ restarted, as well as the conditions for read/open/wait etc. under which these are _not_ restarted in the paragraph before. Otherwise, you'll not know that a signal has occurred (and therefore don't care).

Comment: True, though in my case I am preventing restart. Thanks, my version of that man page doesn't have the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The updated signal(7) man pages has the anwser. The one I was using from RHEL 5.5 did not. Link below.

http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html

Thanks to Damon for the quick anwser!